# Is Shannon entropy always nonnegative?

Tags: information-theory, entropy

$\mathrm {H} (X)=\mathbb {E} [\log \frac{1}{p(X)}]$

Is Shannon entropy always nonnegative? I have heard it can be negative for some continuous distributions. A counterexample or a proof of nonnegativity would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider the continuous uniform distribution over $[0,1/2]$.

Comment: How about searchig for "entropy negative" in this site?

Answer (score 1):

It is always nonnegative for discrete distributions. For continuous distributions
(then called sometimes differential entropy) it can indeed be negative. You can find a standard proof at the first chapter of Thomas and Cover.